# What should be the gradient of the L2 norm of a linear vector function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

I want to compute the gradient of the vector function $f(\vec{x}) = \|\vec{x} - \vec{a}\|$, I have  a try, but the result is kind of strange to me.

so here is my steps
\begin{align*}
\nabla\|\vec{x} - \vec{a}\|  & = \nabla\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - a_i)^2} \\
& = \frac{\nabla \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - a_i)}{2\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - a_i)^2}}\\
\end{align*}

since the gradient of $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - a_i)$ will give back a vector, so I think this should be really the original vector scaling by 2, $2(\vec{x} - \vec{a})$, and then
\begin{align*}
\nabla\|\vec{x} - \vec{a}\|  & =  \frac{\nabla \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - a_i)}{2\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - a_i)^2}}\\
& = \frac{2(\vec{x}-\vec{a})}{2\sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - a_i)^2}}\\
& = \frac{\vec{x} - \vec{a}}{\| \vec{x} - \vec{a} \|_2}
\end{align*}
so it's seems that the gradient of function $f(\vec{x}) = \|\vec{x} - \vec{a}\|$ is really doing the vector normalization? Am I making something mistake at here can someone check this with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly correct. If you remember the conceptual interpretation of the gradient, it makes good sense: The norm increases most rapidly, and with rate 1, if you move from $x$ radially outward from $a$.

Answer (score 0):

The differential approach is much simpler
with almost no computation.

Denote your scalar function
$f = \| \mathbf{z} \|$
where
$\mathbf{z=x-a}$.

From the relation
$f^2 = \mathbf{z} : \mathbf{z}$,
it is easy to obtain
$2 f df = 2 \mathbf{z}:d\mathbf{z}$
and thus
$$
df 
= \frac{1}{f} \mathbf{z} : d\mathbf{z}
= \frac{1}{f} \mathbf{z} : d\mathbf{x}
$$
The gradient is
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=
\frac{1}{f} \left( \mathbf{x-a} \right)
$$